# Android Retrofit + XML response gives this error : java.lang.RuntimeException: org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException

Tags: android, kotlin, xml-parsing, retrofit

I do have an API which returns the following XML response (check the screenshot)

[image]

I am using Retrofit with XML, check my dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
//retrofit XML
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.9.0'
```

When I call the API in Android, I get the response successfully, but I am facing the following error when I get the response.

[image]

This error means that "title" tag is already available inside "channel", so conflict is happening when "title" tag is also available inside "item" tag. If you can see first screenshot of API response, I have highlighted the "title" tag, which is available at first "channel" tag and also inside list of "item".

I am using third-party API so can't change tags in API. I need to make it work for Android.

Here's my data class (POJO class) which takes the response and tries to use it but gets that error:

```
@Root(name = "rss", strict = false)
class RSSFeed @JvmOverloads constructor(
    @field: Element(name = "channel") var channel: PodcastChannel? = null
)

@Root(name = "channel", strict = false)
class PodcastChannel @JvmOverloads constructor(
    @field: Element(name = "title", required = false) var title: String? = null,
    @field: ElementList(inline = true) var itemList: List<PodcastItem>? = null
)

@Root(name = "item", strict = false)
class PodcastItem @JvmOverloads constructor(
    @field: Element(name = "title", required = false) var title: String = "",
    @field: Element(name = "description", required = false) var description: String = "",
)
```

This similar issue is already raised multiple times over [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999265/parsing-xml-feed-die-with-element-is-already-used), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36528870/element-title-is-already-used-with-org-simpleframework-xml-elementlist), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409536/element-name-is-already-used-simple-framework) but didn't get any help from that.

Also, [This Article](https://mak95.medium.com/parsing-xml-data-via-retrofit-2-x-using-kotlin-3ce007d00cf8) on Medium.com has the same API response, so copied his/her data class and tried to make it work, but still, it's not helpful. IDK how his code is working!

Tried all different ways but nothing helped.

Let me know if anyone has done this in the past or made it work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the `Path` annotation for the `itemList` of `PodcastChannel` class:

```
@Root(name = "channel", strict = false)
class PodcastChannel @JvmOverloads constructor(
    @field: Element(name = "title", required = false) 
    var title: String? = null,
    @field: ElementList(inline = true)
    @field: Path("rss/channel")
    var itemList: List<PodcastItem>? = null
)
```

This is an [article](https://etemnogrudova.medium.com/parsing-xml-using-retrofit2-in-kotlin-8e0ff6420bd7) that explains how to use `simpleXml` and the XML response is almost equivalent to the one you're working on. Hope it helps. :D

Comment: Tried this in past and tried again now but same error. No change!

Comment: I updated my answer. Could you take a look and let me know if it works?

Comment: Now it's giving different error. java.lang.RuntimeException: org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Element 'item' is already used with @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList(data=false, empty=true, entry=, inline=false, name=item, required=false, type=void) on field 'itemList' private java.util.List com.app.tfeparentapp.pojo.xml.PodcastChannel.itemList at line 87

Comment: Also, in the above screenshot you can see only one item tag. But there are many tags available (list) one after another. Like <Item>...</item> <item>...</item> <item>...</item>

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I updated my answer. Could you take a look again?

Comment: No man. Didn't work. Now it's not able to get the data inside items :D